# Does hydrogen gas laser exist? If not, why?

Tags: laser, hydrogen

I have searched the internet, and this forum, but can't find a mention of hydrogen gas laser. There does, however, exist the hydrogen maser that used the 21cm radiation. Also there exist Nitrogen gas laser, CO2 gas laser, He-Ne gas laser, and maybe other gas lasers. The question is does it exist? If not, what prevented people from making one?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4159453A/en) patent?

Comment: @ahemmetter , Thank you! From the paper cited by the patent, I found more papers that cited the paper.

Comment: Laser action requires a population inversion.  Not any-old disequilibrium will do.  Some pumped-up level must be slow to depopulate by other mechanisms.